# Internal Android GPS via NTRIP

Tags: android-app, gps-tracking

I am looking for a software that allows me to use the internal GPS of my Android phone by connecting to it with an NTRIP client. I want to be able to use the phone as an rover in RTKNAVI and use a base station and a corrrection service provided by my city to get centimeter accuracy, without the need of investing into any hardware. Can you recommend a software that allows me to use the internal GPS of my Android phone via the network for this?